# Ubuntu terminal has a strange empty area

Tags: 20.04, gnome-terminal, bug-reporting

I noticed something strange while using Ubuntu terminal.
There is an empty area at corner side.
I'd like to use full size window without the empty area.

Is there any good solution?

Please check the picture below. The red square is the strange blank empty space I was talking about.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The font size currently selected doesn't allow all space to be utilized.  If it used an extra line & column, part of the last row & character would appear outside of your window, thus the selected sizing of your `gnome-terminal` (not using all the space).

Comment: the empty space is going to be inside the terminal window or outside of it.  what do you *want* to happen?